# Simple alert event details for FullCalender and using Google Calender

Tags: jquery

I've been stuck with this for about 2 weeks on and off and would appreciate any help from anywhere.

I've created a mini calender on a webpage that uses the FullCalender library. I also have a google calender hooked up to display events in it ([http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/google_calendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/google_calendar/)/).

It all works and displays fine, the issue I'm having is just getting the event details and trying to alert() them, the ultimate aim to create a hover-over pop-up showing details of the event. Research showed that there is a functionality for the FullCalender which allows a 'mouseover' event (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/) which I havnt been able to get to work.

I have also tried accessing the div's HTML using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#pagehome-calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed(
        "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/myrealcalender@email.com/public/basic",
        {

            currentTimezone: 'America/Chicago' // an option!
        }
    )   
});


$(".fc-event-inner").mouseover(function () {
    var htmlStr = $(this).html();
    alert(htmlStr);
});
```

});

However, the function will not trigger which makes me suspect I'm not going to be able to do it this way... can anyone help?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try using jquery delegates for the same as I suspect that the HTML content (i.e. your google calendar) is not ready.
Please refer the [Link here](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

You need to use the same as below:

```
$( document ).delegate( ".fc-event-inner", "mouseover", function() {
var htmlStr = $(this).html();
    alert(htmlStr);
});
```

Comment: From the link: `As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.`

Comment: Thanks for that Akshay and Rory, unfortunatly neither the .delegate() nor the .on() shows any signs of life. They do however work on other normal div's on the page.

Comment: can we see the HTML and the scripts? probably on JsFiddle.net where we may have a better picture to help you out